# InsertIfMissing in Nuget Web.config.install.xdt replaces existing value

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a Nuget package with the following transform in Web.config.install.xdt

```xml
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <foo bar="something" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
</configuration>
```

After the initial install, the consumer will change the attribute-value of `bar`, to ie.

```xml
<configuration>
  <foo bar="someothervalue" />
</configuration>
```

My problem is that on subsequent updates of the the package, I'd like to insert the default value, *only if the node `foo` does not already exist*. With the current transform the node always gets replaced back to

```xml
<configuration>
  <foo bar="something" />
</configuration>
```

I've tried the below expressions in `xdt:Locator` to try and identify if the node already exists without any luck.

```
xdt:Locator="Condition(boolean(//configuration/*[local-name()='foo']))"
xdt:Locator="XPath(/configuration/foo[1])"
```

These work fine when i do 'Preview transform' in Visual Studio, but fails during update of the Nuget package. I guess Nuget only have limited support for these kind of expressions, but I wasn't able to find any documentation on the subject.

I've tested in VS 2015.3 with Nuget Package Manager 3.5.1996 and 3.4.4.1321, and with VS 2017 Preview (26020)

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: is it a custom package or default one? Can you share it here? How did you update you package? Like this document: http://blog.nuget.org/20130920/how-to-use-nugets-xdt-feature-examples-and-facts.html •Insert a section of elements if missing from the current Web.config, does the target section available contain different elements?

Answer (score 0):

According to your Web.config.install.xdt file content, I tested in my Visual Studio 2015.3 with NuGet Package Manager 3.5.1996. The foo node doesn't be replaced when the package updated if foo node is existing in consum project.

Following steps are what I have done, which I have tested with both app.config.install.xdt and Web.config.install.xdt.

1. Create a project (Project A) contains a Web.config.install.xdt and it has the same contents  as yours.
2. Pack the project as a NuGet package and **add the Web.config.install.xdt file into Content folder in this package**.
3. Install this package on another project (Project B) that contains a Web.config file. And the foo node will be added into Web,config with value "something".
4. Modify "something" to "OtherValue" in Web.config and save.
5. Modify some code in the Project A and re-pack it as version 2.0.0.
6. Update the package in Project B and the foo node value still show as "OtherValue".

Please note, after change the foo value, please save your project and rebuild it to make sure it could build successful.

Comment: @Espen Lønnkvist Do you have checked your steps and whether there has any differences? If possible, please share your steps here to help us reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your `.config.uninstall.xdt` file. While upgrading, Nuget removes the old package and then install the new one. So if you put a code that removes all nodes connected to package in uninstall file - you could experience that issue.